# How to escape and validate the body of the request in next js api?

Tags: javascript, validation, next.js, request

Hello I would like to escape or validate the body of the request in next js api.
Before, I use express-validator with express backend but I pass my express backend to next js api.
I saw that I could use [zod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod) but I don't know if I can escape body of the request

For example I use this in my previous express app

```
    import { body } from "express-validator"

    contactRouter.post('/send', body('email').escape().isEmail().withMessage("Email : need to be valid"), send)
```

and In my next api route I don't know where I can do that